# SQL Update Parent Child relation on Trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, parent-child, hierarchy, self-join

I would like to link rows in a self joined table with a trigger.
After an insert in a root table, I would like to create 3 "levels" in the child table.
And each of the level being a hierarchical data (or self joined) such as:

- LVL1

  - LVL2

    - LVL3

Database is SQLSERVER.
I know there is a ton of material about self-joined and hierarchical SQL data, but ... I don't know I've not found what I expected. I've spent too many hours trying solutions, and searching online.

A link to [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1e81f3/4).

Here is the basic schema for example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Root] (
    [RootID] [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Child] (
    [ChildID] [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RootID] [int],
    [Name] [varchar](50),
    [ParentID] [int]
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Child] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [Child_RootID_FK] FOREIGN KEY([RootID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Root] ([RootID]) ON DELETE SET NULL
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Child] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [Child_ParentID_FK] FOREIGN KEY([ParentID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Child] ([ChildID])
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Root_TR]
ON [dbo].[Root]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Child] ([RootID], [Name])
    SELECT
        I.[RootID],
        CONCAT_WS('_', (SELECT [Name] FROM [dbo].[Root] R WHERE R.[RootID] = I.RootID), LVL.n )
    FROM INSERTED I
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS LVL(n)

END
GO


INSERT INTO [dbo].[Root] ([Name]) VALUES (
    'Foo'
)

SELECT * FROM [Root]
SELECT * FROM [Child]
```

I have the current result:

| ChildID | RootID | Name | ParentID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Foo_1 | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | Foo_2 | NULL |
| 3 | 1 | Foo_3 | NULL |

The expected result would be:

| ChildID | RootID | Name | ParentID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Foo_1 | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | Foo_2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | Foo_3 | 2 |

I'm not sure how to achieve this.
I've found a close answer ([here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/258446/pattern-for-copying-hierarchical-data-from-one-table-to-another)) involving usage of SEQUENCE

A solution may be something like:

```
DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[Root_TR]
GO

CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[Sequence] START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Root_TR]
ON [dbo].[Root]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    
    ALTER SEQUENCE [dbo].[Sequence] RESTART

    DECLARE @map TABLE ([ID] [int], [Seq] [int])

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Child] ([RootID], [Name])
    OUTPUT [inserted].ChildID, NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[Sequence] INTO @map
    SELECT
        I.[RootID],
        CONCAT_WS('_', (SELECT [Name] FROM [dbo].[Root] R WHERE R.[RootID] = I.RootID), LVL.n )
    FROM INSERTED I
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS LVL(n)


    UPDATE C 
        SET C.[ParentID] = CASE 
            WHEN M.Seq = 1
                THEN NULL
            ELSE
                (SELECT [Id] FROM @map WHERE [Seq] = [Seq] - 1)
            END
    FROM [dbo].Child C
    INNER JOIN @map M ON C.ChildID = M.ID

END
GO
```

Unfortunately usage of `NEXT VALUE FOR` is not allowed in a `OUTPUT` clause.
`Error 11720 NEXT VALUE FOR function is not allowed in the TOP, OVER, OUTPUT, ON, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, or ORDER BY clauses.`

I cannot relie on `[Name]` column to perform the `UPDATE SET [ParentID] = ... FROM ... JOIN ...`

There is a lot of answers regarding SQL self joined table but I can't really find the answer and my knowledge regarding SQL is limited.

I've attempted something like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Root_TR]
ON [dbo].[Root]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    
    ALTER SEQUENCE [dbo].[Sequence] RESTART

    DECLARE @map TABLE ([ChildID] [int], [Seq] [int])

    DECLARE @i int = NEXT VALUE FOR [Sequence]

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Child] ([RootID], [Name])
    OUTPUT [inserted].ChildID, @i AS [Seq] INTO @map
    SELECT
        I.[RootID],
        CONCAT_WS('_', (SELECT [Name] FROM [dbo].[Root] R WHERE R.[RootID] = I.RootID), LVL.n )
    FROM INSERTED I
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS LVL(n)

    DECLARE @xml xml = (SELECT * FROM @map FOR XML AUTO)
    PRINT CONVERT(nvarchar(max), @xml)

    UPDATE C 
        SET C.[ParentID] = CASE 
            WHEN M.Seq = 1
                THEN NULL
            ELSE
                (SELECT [ChildID] FROM @map WHERE [Seq] = [Seq] - 1)
            END
    FROM [dbo].Child C
    INNER JOIN @map M ON C.ChildID = M.ChildID

END
GO
```

Once again unfortunately the temporary `TABLE @map` is not filled correctly.
The `@i` is called once and do not increment for each output row.

| ChildID | Seq |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 |
| 11 | 1 |
| 12 | 1 |

Another try was to use a `DEFAULT`. But I've an error when creating the trigger: "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.". Probably because the `OUTPUT` clause see more columns available in `@map TABLE` than the number of columns in the `OUTPUT`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Root_TR]
ON [dbo].[Root]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    
    ALTER SEQUENCE [dbo].[Sequence] RESTART

    DECLARE @map TABLE (
        [Seq] [int] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR [Sequence]),
        [ChildID] [int]
    )

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Child] ([RootID], [Name])
    OUTPUT [inserted].ChildID INTO @map
    SELECT
        I.[RootID],
        CONCAT_WS('_', (SELECT [Name] FROM [dbo].[Root] R WHERE R.[RootID] = I.RootID), LVL.n )
    FROM INSERTED I
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS LVL(n)

    DECLARE @xml xml = (SELECT * FROM @map FOR XML AUTO)
    PRINT CONVERT(nvarchar(max), @xml)

    UPDATE C 
        SET C.[ParentID] = CASE 
            WHEN M.Seq = 1
                THEN NULL
            ELSE
                (SELECT [ChildID] FROM @map WHERE [Seq] = [Seq] - 1)
            END
    FROM [dbo].Child C
    INNER JOIN @map M ON C.ChildID = M.ChildID
    
END
GO
```

And the last try was to use a `#table` (I do not distinguish clearly between @x TABLE, TABLE #x, TABLE x). But I want to scope the temporary table to the trigger, and not make the table available globally.
So, this time the `TRIGGER` is created. But when fired, the error message is `Invalid object name 'Sequence'`. I don't know why the `[Sequence]` object is not available in this #table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Root_TR]
ON [dbo].[Root]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    
    ALTER SEQUENCE [dbo].[Sequence] RESTART
    
    CREATE TABLE #map (
        [Seq] [int] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR [Sequence]),
        [ChildID] [int] NOT NULL
    )
    
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Child] ([RootID], [Name])
    OUTPUT [inserted].ChildID INTO #map
    SELECT
        I.[RootID],
        CONCAT_WS('_', (SELECT [Name] FROM [dbo].[Root] R WHERE R.[RootID] = I.RootID), LVL.n )
    FROM INSERTED I
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS LVL(n)

    DECLARE @xml xml = (SELECT * FROM #map FOR XML AUTO)
    PRINT CONVERT(nvarchar(max), @xml)

    UPDATE C 
        SET C.[ParentID] = CASE 
            WHEN M.Seq = 1
                THEN NULL
            ELSE
                (SELECT [ChildID] FROM #map WHERE [Seq] = [Seq] - 1)
            END
    FROM [dbo].Child C
    INNER JOIN #map M ON C.ChildID = M.ChildID

END
GO
```

So finally I don't have yet any solution to properly link my different levels with their parents.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just use an `IDENTITY` column on the table variable, instead of a `SEQUENCE`

Comment: Why do you need to create 2 "children" after you insert a value in the first place? Also, why are you inserting the root into the child table as well? Surely the root should just be in the root table? If it needs to be in the child table, why does the root table exist? It's just duplicating data, and there's no need for that. This feels a bit like an XY Problem, if I am honest.

Comment: Hum, this may be an idea for sure. I was inspired by the link provided. At least the table variable is filled correctly, but my `UPDATE` statement doesn't work for the moment.

Comment: Maybe the design isn't good, or this example too many simplified, I don't know.
This may be by example a hard drive, ..e C:, D: ... on Windows.
And the child table may be a nested folder structure linked to a drive.
So I have C:\Folder1, C:\Folder1\Folder2, C:\Folder3.
This is just an example and it isn't related to my real objects, but if the design is wrong I would like to know why @Larnu.

Comment: I don't have enough information at this point, but creating children by a trigger, and always 2, feels odd and duplicating the data *is* wrong.

Comment: @Charlieface This works with the Identity table provided the minor update below on the `UPDATE` statement.
```
 UPDATE C 
  SET C.[ParentID] = CASE 
   WHEN M.Seq = 1
    THEN NULL
   ELSE
    (SELECT [ChildID] FROM #map WHERE [Seq] = M.[Seq] - 1)
   END
 FROM [dbo].Child C
 INNER JOIN #map M ON C.ChildID = M.ChildID
```

Comment: I don't understand why you think I duplicate the data. For me I'm just "linking" some child data with a "unique" parent in a 1 to n relationship. The fact that I'm creating the different child objects (linked together) on a parent insertion is that I want to provision the child data immediately. For sure this may be "application-driven", meaning that when a parent is successfully inserted, I may insert myself the child objects without relying on a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the complete trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Root_TR]
ON [dbo].[Root]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    
    CREATE TABLE #map (
        [Seq] [int] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
        [ChildID] [int] NOT NULL
    )
    
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Child] ([RootID], [Name])
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ChildID INTO #map
    SELECT
        I.[RootID],
        CONCAT_WS('_', (SELECT [Name] FROM [dbo].[Root] R WHERE R.[RootID] = I.RootID), LVL.n )
    FROM INSERTED I
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS LVL(n)

    UPDATE C 
        SET C.[ParentID] = CASE 
            WHEN M.[Seq] = 1
                THEN NULL
            ELSE
                (SELECT [ChildID] FROM #map WHERE [Seq] = M.[Seq] - 1)
            END
    FROM [dbo].Child C
    INNER JOIN #map M ON C.ChildID = M.ChildID

END
GO
```